# Why is navbar breaking in when i re-size the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `logo and Account Name` in my `navbar` which works fine in desktop and larger devices. The moment when I re-size to tablet or mobile resolution, it breaks.

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">        
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                   <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Something</a></li>
                  <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                  <li><h4 style="margin-top: 15px">ACME - New York</h4></li>
                </ul>                                  
             </div>
            </div>                             
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Below is the a jsbin I have been working. Why does the AccountName/Logo come down when I resize?.

http://jsbin.com/focataru/13

Answer (score 0):

Because you set 50percent width and that's all. Set fixed width or min-width if you want. For example min-width: 420px;

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using a responsive layout.

Below a certain threshold the `li` elements change from being `float: left` to being `position: relative; display: block`.

Look at the non-minified version of the bootstrap css at the media-query parts.

This is desired as at low screen widths you would not fit an entire menu block in - so it goes vertical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div to span across the entire row set its column size to `12`:

```
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Something</a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><h4 style="margin-top: 15px">ACME - New York</h4></li>
         </ul>                                  
       </div>
    </div>
```

Then add the following to the CSS to eliminate some of the responsiveness:

```
.navbar li{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: `class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12"` can be greatly simplified to `class="col-xs-12"`